# What is the difference between returning new object immediately?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

What is the difference between these two:

```
try
{
    MyClass* tmp=new MyClass;
    return tmp
}
catch (...)
{
    cout << "Error";
}
```

and

```
try
{
    return new MyClass;
}
catch (...)
{
    cout << "Error";
}
```

I think that if an error happened in the second one it will return immediately and not catch the error, right?

Comment: Assuming Johnny's guess is correct, the advantage to having a `tmp` variable is that it is easier to see in the debugger.  There is a lot of value to that.  For those who are concerned about the overhead, in an optimized build the optimizer is really, really good at eliminating that kind of overhead.

Comment: @NathanOliver Updated

Comment: Why do you think the second example won't catch an exception?

Comment: By the way, if I'm not mistaking, this could cause a memory leak. Use smart pointers instead.

Comment: @H-005 By itself this code does not cause a memory leak. If the ctor for `MyClass` threw an exception the memory allocated would be freed. But of course using a smart point is still good advice.

Comment: @dan Of course the two pieces of code are identical. Sometimes the obvious thing is true.

Comment: @dan There is no difference.  A compiler will turn `MyClass* tmp=new MyClass; return tmp` into `return new MyClass;`.

Comment: The difference is that in the first version, you can easily single step or place a breakpoint and see the value before the value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

They do exactly the same thing.
And will (most likely) generate exactly the same code.

The first one though is helpful if you are using an interactive debugger. After the new is complete it is easier to just check the object (by click on `tmp` (or typing `print tmp` into the debug console)) and see if was initialized correctly.

Not something you do often but it comes up.

Answer (score 0):

The two pieces of code will accomplish the same thing. The first one will more easily allow you to see the value of tmp in a debugger or add a line to print its value while debugging.

Unrelated to your question: why are you using new? It is generally better to use std::unique_ptr and std::make_unique instead of a raw pointer and new. std::unique_ptr will also refer to a dynamically allocated instance of MyClass, but will automatically call delete when it goes out of scope, making it less likely for you to have memory leaks in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Both have same functions.
For the try{ } and catch(...) will also work fine in case there are error during allocating memory for MyClass.

But I personally prefer the new method, as sometimes I will do something before return the class.